# Making python program for calculating integral

Tags: python, math, integral

I have a Python program for calculating the integral of a function in just one point. But this is simply not effective as I want to calculate more x values at the same time, not just one value. Anyone have any idea?

```
from scitools.std import *
def trapezoidal(f,a,x,n):
    h = (x-a)/float(n)
    I = 0.5*f(a)
    for i in iseq(1, n-1):
        I += f(a+i*h)
    I += 0.5*f(x)
    I *= h
    return I

class Integral:
    def __init__(self, f, a, n=100):
        self.f, self.a, self.n = f,a,n
    def __call__(self,x):
        return trapezoidal(self.f,self.a,x,self.n)
```

Comment: if you want to calculate the integral at several points -- maybe you could use piecewise cubic interpolation to get a function, `g`, which approximates `f` and can be integrated in closed (albeit piecewise) form. Alternatively -- if you need to do many numerical integrations perhaps you could consider using Simpson's rule rather than using the trapezoidal since (absent special considerations) Simpson's rule converges much more rapidly and is almost as easy to program.